# OSDK Interconnection problems

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm trying to connet from the osdk (Raspberry Pi 4 with Linux) to MSDK, but when the next sentence are executing nothing happends:

vehicle->mopServer->accept((PipelineID)MOBILE_PIPELINE_ID, UNRELIABLE, mobile_Pipeline)

In the console appear this:

[1185439.581]STATUS/1 @ accept, L50: /*! 0.Find whether the pipeline object is existed or not */

[1185439.581]STATUS/1 @ accept, L56: /*! 1.Create handler for binding */

[1185439.581]STATUS/1 @ accept, L64: /*! 2.Do binding */

[1185441.581]STATUS/1 @ accept, L77: /*! 3.Do accepting */

[1185441.581]STATUS/1 @ accept, L78: Do accepting blocking for channel [49154]

But never ends, the program stay like "sleeping". I waited for many minutes and nothing.

Please, can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: tried it before with older msdk and osdk 3.3 3.4 era.  The newer one never test anymore.